# Multiplayer on Minecraft PE gone with update to version 12?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

My son and I have been playing for months on our iPads using multiplayer mode. We could join in the same world that one would host.

With the latest upgrade to version 12, even with multiplayer on, we cannot see each other's world to join (there used to be the radiating green signal).

Is this option gone or is there a new way to join?

Both devices are running the same platform. Thank you.

Comment: And by 'same platform', what version are you referring to? What version of Minecraft are you playing in as well? Are you behind a firewall or anything? There's not much information for us to work with here.

Comment: Sorry, I'm not entirely savvy with these things. Our iPads received the same updates at the same time. It's the latest 12 edition just released earlier this month. He would start a world, I would see his in my list of worlds to join (through that radiating green signal) and I'd join him. Now that signal is gone and we can't join in the same world anymore.

Comment: seemingly related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/237202/minecraft-pe-no-more-multi-server

Comment: Christine, that's just another question on this site with what seems to be the same problem as you. There's also [this forum](http://www.minecraftforum.net/forums/support/minecraft-pocket-edition-support/2523004-minecraft-pe-multiplayer-problems-v0-12-1) where there are many people complaining about the same issue after the newest patch. It looks like the patch introduced a bug, it's likely there will be another patch soon fixing whatever they broke.

Comment: Yes, that's what happened to us too. I'm hoping its a glitch. We really had fun playing together, when he's not blowing me up with TNT that is :)

Comment: Thank you for the info. I'll keep checking back to see if a solution comes out.

Comment: Maybe in the meantime you could try reinstalling an older version (if that's possible)

Comment: I'll leave as is for now. He'll live. Hopefully it will be fixed soon. I don't want to mess with it further and risk messing something else up. I'm sure with others having the issue a patch will be out soon. Thank you again.

Comment: Christine try this: click the `new` button as if creating a new world then click the button the left of the `advanced` button that looks like a plus with an arrow pointing to the right. Enter the IP address of the other device, leave the port as default (assuming you haven't changed it) then click add server button. Now click the back button and see if the server is in the list of worlds now.

Answer (score -1):

Make sure that you have a Microsoft account and the "Xbox Xpp". This worked for me.