# Minecraft PE, no more multi server?

Tags: minecraft-bedrock-edition

Since the new update of mincraft PE, my kid can no longer connect to any local servers, or play on a server such as Lifeboat...Everything worked fine for 2 years, then after the update, it just didn't work anymore. We have not changed a thing, no do we use an outside app for servers. Just our local area connection...can't seem to find an answer. I know that mojang says we are now suppose to be able to play cross platform, but our windows 10 does not seem to be picking up any servers , such as our ipads or visa versa either...any clue what is happening?

Comment: seemingly related: http://gaming.stackexchange.com/questions/237199/multiplayer-on-minecraft-pe-gone-with-update

Comment: try this: click the new button as if creating a new world then click the button the left of the advanced button that looks like a plus with an arrow pointing to the right. Enter the IP address of the other device, leave the port as default (assuming you haven't changed it) then click add server button. Now click the back button and see if the server is in the list of worlds now